# CSV row jump function

Tags: python, csv, flask

I am trying to make a form with Flask and Python, I want to save the elements I get from the templates in a CSV file.

I made a function that should save the data of the templates in a row and when it arrives to the last template save in the CSV row and make a row jump.

However, instead of saving the information in the same row of the csv, it writes the last element obtained from the template in a new row, and it should be saved in the same row:

[image]

The code of the function is as follows:

```
def write(test,final):
    lista=[]
    for x in test:
        print(test[x])
        lista.append(test[x])
    with open('covid.csv', 'a') as f:
        if final == '0':
            print("Dentro de if 0")
            for line in lista:
                name=io.StringIO(line)
                coma=io.StringIO(",")
                f.write(str(name.read()))
                f.write(str(coma.read()))
        if final == '1':
            print("Dentro de if 1")
            for line in lista:
                name=io.StringIO(line)
                coma=io.StringIO(",")
                f.write(str(name.read()))
                f.write(str(coma.read()))
            f.write(str("\n")
```

This function is called as follows:

```
@app.route('/sintomas', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sintomas():
    print("Prueba de datos:")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.form.to_dict()
        print(test)
        write(test,'0')
    return render_template('nuevaplantilla6.html')

@app.route('/signos', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sintomas2():
    print("Prueba de datos:")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.form.to_dict()
        print(test)
        write(test,'1')
    return render_template('plantilla7.html')
```

Comment: Unrelated question: Why do you do this `coma=io.StringIO(","); f.write(str(coma.read()))` instead of just `f.write(",")`?

Comment: Could you please add a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, i.e. a little sample of `test`.

Comment: For us to test your code, we need you to [edit] the question to include an example of `test` so the function could be called. Also please show what your expected output would be for this example